# How to use share data between two components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a Shared Component (an input search bar with a "continue" button) that I am using inside two other components (buy component and sell component).
I want to hide the "continue" button of my search bar component in my buy component while show it in my Sell component.
To achieve that I have used @Input continueButtonCheck in my buy component and it hides the button on my buy module's component but also hides it in sell component as well. I need the same continueButtonCheck and pass it to my other component (sell component).

the shared component looks something like this:

(shared) search-bar-component.html file:

```
<input />
<button *ngIf="continueButtonCheck">continue</button>
```

this is used in both of my other components.

An example can be found here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jaqbnn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbuy%2Fbuy.component.ts

the issue I am facing is that I don't know how to access that "continueButtonCheck" property inside my sell component.

Comment: When do you need it? You could `@Output` it when there's something happening in the search component, e.g. typing or pressing the button.

Comment: The `@Input` property is undefined so the button won't be rendered unless set explicitly in the parent component. You could define a default value instead `@Input() continueSearchButton = true;` in **search.component.ts**. I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ceqpy1?file=src/app/search/search.component.ts).

Comment: yeah, it works the way I want it to, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because  `@Input() continueSearchButton` is default undefined. Soin `<button *ngIf="continueSearchButton">Continue</button>` `continueSearchButton` will be false  and it will hide the button.

So you can set `@Input() continueSearchButton = true;` default to `true`. If you need to hide the button you can do like you did in buy component